# How do i give other users permissions for modules?

Tags: users

I have the following question: How do I give other users permissions for modules?
Example: [FAQ](https://drupal.org/project/faq) module.

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you mean with 'permissions for modules'? Permission to configure that module?

Answer (score 1):

To adminster the permissions for a module navigate to  *Administration » People » Permissions*.  There you will find a panel where you can assign permissions for the various modules.  The section for the [FAQ](https://drupal.org/project/faq) (Frequently Asked Questions) module is shown below:

[image]

As you can see, this module have three separate permissions:

- Administer FAQ module
- Administer FAQ order
- View FAQ pages

To grant as specific role a permission, you tick the mark to the right of the permission and below the role.

In the screen shot above, all roles are granted the right to "View FAQ pages", but only the administrator is granted the other two permissions.